# raphael text() in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, raphael

Trying to get [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/) to work with IE8.

I am using the text() function to draw some text, which works perfectly in FF3 and Chrome, but not in IE8 (neither compat nor regular IE8).

Other drawing stuff works well in IE8, so I'd guess I am missing some stupid minor detail on how to render **text** in Raphael.

Oh and this is their latest 0.8.6 version of the library.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got It!

Can not set font size in em in IE, for some reason. Setting font-size in "px" works perfectly well. Who could have known?...

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  IE8 does not respect 'pt' sizes either, so I had to use 'px' sizes.  Thankfully, the change did not affect other browsers.